# Can't Put Image Over Image

Tags: html, css, image

Edit: The solutions HAVE to have `display: inline-block;`

I'm trying to put an iframe over an image. However, no matter what I set the margin-right to, it stays in the same spot. About 1/5 of the background image.

HTML

```
<div class="backgroundimage">
  <img src="http://truespeed.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/tvscreen.png" alt="null" />
  <iframe class="Youtube" width="479" height="269" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6ydYvG52K-E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.backgroundimage {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  bottom: 46px;
}
.Youtube {
  position: absolute;
  left: 280px;
  bottom: 46px;
  right: 380px;
}
```

And a picture of my issue:

[image: issue]

Comment: This? https://jsfiddle.net/yb43y4nd/

Comment: Is there a reason for setting `top` and `left` on the container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change `left` to a smaller value in the `.Youtube` rule (that's *left of the parent elements left side*). Start at about 10px and find the ideal position by trying.

ADDITION: You also *have to erase* the `right: 380px;` from your `.Youtube` rule - it overwrites the `left` rule (since it follows below it ("cascading")).

Comment: please note the addition to my answer

Comment: Thank you!  You've figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the positioning. Just changed the margins and paddings.

```css
.backgroundimage {
  position: relative;
}
.Youtube {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  left: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgroundimage">
  <img src="http://truespeed.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/tvscreen.png" alt="null" />
  <iframe class="Youtube" width="479" height="269" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6ydYvG52K-E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: This would work; however I need my inline-block.  Else my div becomes the size of my parent div (the page itself).  I need something smaller.

Comment: What do you mean by smaller? You want the iframe to be smaller?

Comment: No, with display set to block, the backgroundimage div is the size of the entry-content div.  I want it to be as big as the TV image.

Comment: No, the div is stretches the entire width of the page (in the case of this snippet).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125238/discussion-between-thomas-hutton-and-k-daniek).

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.container { position:relative; }
.imgA1 { position:absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1; } 
.imgB1 { position:absolute; top: 70px; left: 100px; z-index: 3; } 
</style>
```

---

```
<div class="container">
<img class="imgA1" src="image1.png">
<img class="imgB1" src="image2.png">
</div>
```

If you want you can add more image.

Answer (score 0):

This is as similar as I can make to your code, while showing the image over the iframe:

```
img {
    position:absolute;
  left: 280px;
}

.backgroundimage {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  bottom: 46px;
}
.Youtube {
  position: absolute;
  left: 280px;
}

<div class="backgroundimage">
  <iframe class="Youtube" width="479" height="269" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6ydYvG52K-E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <img src="http://truespeed.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/tvscreen.png" alt="null" />
</div>
```

The main thing I've done is added `position:absolute` to the image

Answer (score 0):

You'll never need to set both `left` and `right` when the width of an element is known. Just one of the two will suffice.

```
.backgroundimage {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
    bottom: 46px;
}
.Youtube {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 22px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjusted the absolute position of the video.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLOdov

```
.backgroundimage {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  bottom: 46px;
}
.Youtube {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 380px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="backgroundimage">
 <img src="http://truespeed.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/tvscreen.png" alt="null" />
  <iframe class="Youtube" width="479" height="269" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6ydYvG52K-E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
  .backgroundimage {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      top: 70px;
      bottom: 46px;
    }
    .Youtube {
      position: absolute;
      left: 10px;
      bottom: 52px;
    }
```

Fiddel

https://jsfiddle.net/dhavalpatel/a2bhnw92/

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late..

How about a very nice lightweight way of keeping it responsive by percentages? The resizing works flawlessly on all devices.

To add a width..add `max-width:500px` in the photo div, or whatever size you want, it will perfectly resize.

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#photo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#movie {
position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 90%;
    height: 75%;
    top: 6.75%;
    left: 4.25%;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="photo">
    <img src="http://truespeed.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/tvscreen.png" width="100%" height="auto">
    <div id="movie">
       <iframe class="Youtube" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6ydYvG52K-E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>    </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/edn2ua31/)